# How can I make a grid with checkboxes that maintain state between page loads?

Tags: extjs, extjs3

How can we make checkboxes remain checked when the page is refreshed in a Sencha ExtJS 3.3.0 GridPanel?

I have a GridPanel which displays some information with checkboxes. When the page is refreshed, the checkbox should still be checked.

Any suggestions, ideas, or code samples?

Comment: Hi, you can get more specific help if you post some of your code or provide more details about what you've tried.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem and I fixed it in such way - manually save id's of records that I show in cookies. Solution is not beautiful, but works for me.

```
store.on({
    'beforeload': function () {              
        var checkeditems = [];
        for(var i=0;i<gridResources.selModel.selected.length;i++)
        {                           checkeditems.push(grid.selModel.selected.items[i].data.ID);
        }
        if(checkeditems.length>0)
            setCookie("RDCHECKBOXES", checkeditems.join("|"));
    },
    'load': function () {
        if (getCookie("RDCHECKBOXES")) {
            var checkeditems = getCookie("RDCHECKBOXES").split("|");
            for (var i = 0; i<gridResources.store.data.items.length && checkeditems.length>0; i++) {
                for(var j=0;j<checkeditems.length;j++) {
                    if (gridResources.store.data.items[i].data.ID == checkeditems[j]) {
                        gridResources.selModel.select(gridResources.store.data.items[i], true);
                        checkeditems.splice(j, 1);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Here are code for functions getCookie() and setCookie():

```
// Example:
// setCookie("foo", "bar", "Mon, 01-Jan-2001 00:00:00 GMT", "/");
function setCookie (name, value, expires, path, domain, secure) {
      document.cookie = name + "=" + escape(value) +
        ((expires) ? "; expires=" + expires : "") +
        ((path) ? "; path=" + path : "") +
        ((domain) ? "; domain=" + domain : "") +
        ((secure) ? "; secure" : "");
}

// Example:
// myVar = getCookie("foo");
function getCookie(name) {
    var cookie = " " + document.cookie;
    var search = " " + name + "=";
    var setStr = null;
    var offset = 0;
    var end = 0;
    if (cookie.length > 0) {
        offset = cookie.indexOf(search);
        if (offset != -1) {
            offset += search.length;
            end = cookie.indexOf(";", offset)
            if (end == -1) {
                end = cookie.length;
            }
            setStr = unescape(cookie.substring(offset, end));
        }
    }
    return(setStr);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you looked at all at the [ExtJS documentation](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/3-4/) or the [included samples](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-3.3.1/examples/)? There's a [sample grid](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-3.3.1/examples/grid/edit-grid.html) using the CheckColumn extension that does exactly what you ask.

In the example linked, take note that the checkbox column is linked to a boolean record field

```
// in your record
{name: 'indoor', type: 'bool'}
```

and represented in the grid's column model by a CheckColumn:

```
// in the grid's column model
xtype: 'checkcolumn',
header: 'Indoor?',
dataIndex: 'indoor',
width: 55
```

This way, when boolean data comes into the store from the server in JSON or XML, the values are represented as checkboxes in the grid. As long as you write your changes to the server, your checkbox boolean values will be preserved.

Comment: No it doesn't. It doesn't save state between page refreshes.